# Update to pyodbc 4 causes "Segmentation fault"

Tags: pyodbc, django-pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure

I have a Django+celery site running on Elastic Beanstalk that used pyodbc 3.  Because of another issue, I had to update to pyodbc 4.

However, the web site starting giving error 500 and this is the information logged:

```
[Fri Feb 24 20:02:14.448536 2017] [core:notice] [pid 27978] AH00052: child pid 28292 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Fri Feb 24 20:02:15.145503 2017] [core:error] [pid 27988] [client 205.165.34.225:50040] End of script output before headers: wsgi.py, referer: ...
```

During that time the Celery worker was still running and working just fine!  I've re-deployed the whole server (Rebuild Environment in AWS) and it didn't fix the issue.

I had to revert to pyodbc 3 and it started working just fine.  Any ideas?

django 1.10.4, pyodbc 4.0.11, django-pyodbc-azure 1.10.0.1

Comment: If you have reason to believe that this is a bug in pyodbc 4.x then you probably should report it as an issue [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues).

Comment: @GordThompson I couldn't say it's a bug, I'm pretty new to Linux and Django, so it could easily be a configuration problem

Comment: When you say " I've re-deployed the whole server and it fixed the issue" do you mean that it started working with pyodbc 4.x after the re-deploy, or that the re-deploy reverted pyodbc back to 3.x?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say "it didn't fix the issue" clicking on "Rebuild Environment". I'll correct the question

Answer (score 2):

We have run into this issue as well, and will be providing a stack trace and related information to `pyodbc` on Monday. We've fixed it by pinning our requirements like this:

```
pyodbc==3.1.1
django-pyodbc-azure==1.10.4.0
```

While this doesn't get you `pyodbc` 4.0 yet, it will work for the rest of your site. We had some luck using `4.0.5` for running the site, but ran into some issues with migrations. (Note: if you use `django-pyodbc-azure`, you should use the highest version that matches your Django version, I.e. `1.10.4.0` for Django 1.10.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but I believe I need v4 to fix some encoding issues https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/112 do you know if that's fixed in v3.1.1 (I believe it's not).

Comment: I won't get a chance to test more until tomorrow, but you could try versions < 4.0.11. Perhaps try `pip install pyodbc==4.0.0`?

Comment: The issue is already reported here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/181?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container Please add any info you can so this can get fixed ASAP. I don't know how to provide such info. Thank you.